# Can I set signposts before and after a call in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, logging, methods, signpost

I watched [Getting started with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/) and there they show the usage of **Signposts**. The example is written in *Swift* but I'd like to use them with my *Objective-C* project.

In these example the signpost start and end are set inside the function which means they will be triggered accordingly. My project is a plugin and its structured differently where I only have a "main" function that gets called once and then I use a series of methods from a custom class to load and parse different kind of data. As it is all sequential ... can I have only one `os_log_t` and `os_signpost_id_t` and reutilize it over and over again with `os_signpost_interval_begin` + `os_signpost_interval_end`? Or is this not safe as the method could return after the `end` was triggered? Or could they have conflicts if they get called meny times so quickly?

Thanks.

```c
// Initialize
os_log_t log = os_log_create("com.example.plugin", OS_LOG_CATEGORY_POINTS_OF_INTEREST);
os_signpost_id_t spid = os_signpost_id_generate(log);

// Measurement 1 
os_signpost_interval_begin(log, spid, "testMethodA started");
[MyClass testMethodA:arg1 withOptions:arg2];
os_signpost_interval_end(log, spid, "testMethodA finished");

// Measurement 2
os_signpost_interval_begin(log, spid, "testMethodB started");
[MyClass testMethodB:arg1 withOptions:arg2];
os_signpost_interval_end(log, spid, "testMethodB finished");

[...]
```

Answer (score 8):

Ok I found the problem. I was using a different `name` for the `os_signpost_interval_begin` and `os_signpost_interval_end` and therefore it was not being ended and just started.

The code should look like this:

```c
// Measurement 1 
os_signpost_interval_begin(log, spid, "testMethodA");
[MyClass testMethodA:arg1 withOptions:arg2];
os_signpost_interval_end(log, spid, "testMethodA");
```